# Sum only numeric characters from a string column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add only the numeric characters of a SQL Server string column, but in the same column there are also text data, do you know if it is possible to ignore the text data and add only numeric values? Thanks

Example (sum the column VALOR1 ignoring the string **'teste'**:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do you mean "ignore text data and add only numeric values"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY_CAST will convert invalid values to NULL

> `SELECT SUM(TRY_CAST(VALOR1 AS INT))`